# How to totally eliminate the gap before the first element span of the page

Tags: html, css

Here's the code  of `body` of my HTML code. I've an image with a H1 title inside a span which is fixed at the top of the page. But there's a little that I cannot remove (see picture). How can I totally remove this gap ?

```
<body style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
<span style="position: fixed; background:white;padding:0px;margin:0px;width:100%">
    <h1 style="margin:0px;padding:0px">Aide en ligne</h1>

    <p><img width="535" height="397" src=
    "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image003.png" v:shapes=
    "Image_x0020_1" /></p></span>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      <ol>
          <li>Rubriques du fichier fournisseur que vous pouvez exporter</li>
          <li>Ces boutons vous permettent&nbsp;d&rsquo;ajouter ou de supprimer des rubriques
      dans la liste &agrave; exporter. Pour ce faire, s&eacute;lectionner une ou
      plusieurs rubriques puis&nbsp;cliquez sur l&rsquo;un de ces boutons&nbsp;:<ol>
              <li>
              <img width="33" height="24" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image004.png" v:shapes=
      "Image_x0020_19" />&nbsp;ajouter une rubrique dans la liste des rubriques &agrave;
      exporter</li>
              <li>
              <img width="33" height="24" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image005.png" v:shapes=
      "Image_x0020_20" />&nbsp;ajouter toutes les rubriques dans la liste &agrave;
      exporter</li>
              <li>
              <img width="30" height="21" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image006.png" v:shapes=
      "_x0000_i1025" />&nbsp;retirer une rubrique de la liste &agrave; exporter</li>
              <li>
              <img width="33" height="24" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image007.png" v:shapes=
      "Image_x0020_22" />&nbsp;retirer toutes les rubriques de la liste &agrave;
      exporter</li>
          </ol>
          </li>
          <li>Ce tableau indique toutes les rubriques du fichier fournisseur qui seront
      export&eacute;es dans le fichier Excel, <i>dans l&rsquo;ordre
      affich&eacute;</i></li>
          <li>Ces boutons vous permettent de changer l&rsquo;ordre des
      rubriques&nbsp;&agrave; exporter</li>
          <li>S&eacute;lectionnez une rubrique</li>
          <li>Cliquez sur le bouton monter ou descendre pour changer l&rsquo;ordre de cette
      rubrique<br /><br />Note&nbsp;: vous pouvez &eacute;galement changer l&rsquo;ordre des rubriques
      simplement en les faisant glisser&nbsp;:<br />
          <img width="362" height="171" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image008.png" alt=
      "https://i.snipboard.io/jsFXlG.jpg" v:shapes="Image_x0020_23" /></li>
          <li>Il est possible dans le fichier Excel de choisir ce qui devra appara&icirc;tre
      dans l&rsquo;ent&ecirc;te : le libell&eacute; des rubriques ou le nom des rubriques
      ou les 2. <b>Pour une exploitation future (importation, &hellip;) il est
      conseill&eacute; d&rsquo;exporter avec le nom des rubriques</b></li>
          <li>Cochez cette case si vous souhaitez &eacute;galement exporter les agences
      reli&eacute;es aux fournisseurs. Le principe d&rsquo;agencement des rubriques
      &agrave; exporter est le m&ecirc;me qu&rsquo;avec les fournisseurs. Les points qui
      suivent sont valables uniquement si vous choisissez effectivement d&rsquo;exporter
      les agences</li>
          <li>Cette option permet de g&eacute;n&eacute;rer dans Excel une ligne qui ne
      contiendra que le fournisseur. Les lignes suivantes seront celles de l&rsquo;agence
      avec les donn&eacute;es fournisseurs r&eacute;p&eacute;t&eacute;es. Cela
      peut-&ecirc;tre utile pour r&eacute;aliser des filtres dans Excel. Exemple (avec
      mise en gras)&nbsp;:<br />
          <img width="707" height="203" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image009.png" v:shapes=
      "Image_x0020_24" /></li>
          <li>Voir exemple ci-dessus</li>
          <li>Lancer l&rsquo;exportation (en choisissant le nom du fichier)</li>
          <li>Si vous souhaitez conserver la configuration pour une utilisation
      ult&eacute;rieure, utilisez ce bouton. Il vous sera ensuite propos&eacute; de
      fournir un nom &agrave; cette configuration&nbsp;:<br />
          <img width="396" height="158" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image010.png" v:shapes=
      "Image_x0020_25" /></li>
          <li>Ce bouton vous permettra de recharger une configuration que vous avez ainsi
      sauvegard&eacute;&nbsp;:<br />
          <img width="380" height="259" src=
      "export%20fourn%2024761%2024762%2024763_fichiers/image011.png" v:shapes=
      "Image_x0020_27" /></li>
      </ol>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've simply added "top: 0px" to the span and it Works. Perhaps there's another solution ?

Comment: This shouldn’d _need_ any “different solution.” If you don’t _specify_ `top`, then fixed or absolute positioning will take the implicit top position the element would have in _normal_ flow, as the default value. You _want_ to specify something different here though, so the “solution” is to simply do that then.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation !